# SOQL query to get the Email Template Id?

Tags: apex, soql

I have an email template and I want to get the Id of the email template say XYZ. How we can get that? I tried below query but it gives me different Id

```
SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'XYZ'
```

When I click on the email template, it open in the browser and gives me Id say https://cs53.salesforce.com/00X0XXXXXXXXX, I want the 00X0XXXXXXXXX.

How we can get that ?

Comment: They're the same thing. The UI typically uses 15 character ID values, and the API (e.g. Apex) typically uses the 18 character ID value. They're interchangeable.

Comment: See [knowledge article 4383](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004383&type=1) and [knowledge article 5288](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005288&language=en_US&type=1), [this search](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=18+15), etc. You can use either of them anywhere that an EmailTemplate ID is a legal value (e.g. for rendering or sending using Messaging.sendEmail).

Comment: What do you mean it gives you a different `Id`? Are you sure you got the correct `DeveloperName`?

Comment: A great tool is https://sf1518.click/ , which converts between the formats (and quiets my anxiety about when to use which format). Pretty much all out-of-the-box SFDC stuff uses them both interchangeably.